# Flutter Web--Location permission does not work on Safari(Mac & iOS)

Tags: flutter, safari, flutter-web

I am trying to request location in my app. It works in iOS, Android, and every browser except Safari on Mac and iOS.

### EDIT

Since none of the plugins worked for Safari, I decided to go with native dart2js solution.

```dart
@JS('navigator.geolocation')
library jslocation;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('getCurrentPostion')
external void getCurrentPostion(Function success(GeolocationPostion pos));

@JS()
@anonymous
class GeolocationPostion {
  external factory GeolocationPostion({GeolocationCoordinates coords});

  external GeolocationCoordinates get coords;
}

@JS()
@anonymous
class GeolocationCoordinates {
  external factory GeolocationCoordinates({
    double latitude,
    double longitude,
  });

  external double get latitude;
  external double get longitude;
}



double _latitude;
        double _longitude;

        getCurrentPostion((pos) => allowInterop((GeolocationPostion pos) {
              _latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
              _longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
            }));

        return LocationData.fromMap({
          'latitude': _latitude,
          'longitude': _longitude,
        });
```

The solution is copied wholesale from [here](https://flatteredwithflutter.com/detect-user-location-in-flutter-web/). The [demo for this](https://web.flatteredwithflutter.com/#/) post works fine with on Safari. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the only difference I see is that the demo get location when pressing a button! could you try this?

Comment: Do you get any console errors that you can feedback from Safari Mac?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No console errors as well.

Comment: have u found the solution?

Comment: @PRATHIV I use reverse geocoding API when its Safari. I am using mapbox, you can use Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reputable package [`geolocator` by Baseflow](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), see that it has the [Flutter favorite badget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/favorites).

You can check the [web docs](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/tree/master/geolocator#usage) and the [example](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/blob/master/geolocator_web/example/lib/main.dart) they provide, and maybe this fits with your problem.

Good luck !

Comment: This was the oeiginal solution tried